# Multiple COUNT fields, GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, group-by, count

I'm trying to group two columns in my MySQL database and show counts for them respectively (as separate columns). Is there a way of doing this or do I have to join two sub-queries?

I'm aware of `WITH ROLLUP` but can't produce the right query.

This gives the right result:

```
SELECT A.mid, B.pid, A.count AS mid_count, B.count as pid_count
  FROM (Select mid , COUNT(*) AS count FROM test GROUP BY mid) AS A,
  (Select mid, pid, COUNT(*) AS count FROM test GROUP BY mid, pid) AS B 
  WHERE A.mid = B.mid ORDER BY mid_count DESC
```

This is the expected output

```
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+
| mid | pid | mid_count | pid_count |
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+
|   3 |  12 |         5 |         2 |
|   3 |  14 |         5 |         1 |
|   3 |  15 |         5 |         2 |
|   4 |  12 |         2 |         1 |
|   4 |  17 |         2 |         1 |
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

I've created a fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3ebe1/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed one of the subqueries from yours but fundamentally as mysql doesn't support count over partition etc, it will need more than one pass through the table:

```
Select test.mid, test.pid, A.cnt as midCount, count(*) as pidCount
from test join
(Select mid, count(*) as cnt from test group by mid) A
on test.mid =  A.mid
Group by mid, pid
```

Answer (score 0):

## ALTERNATE QUERY

I have a query that will do the following

- Only one subquery
- One `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`
- Here is the catch: the mid count is a separate row instead of a column

Here is the query

```
SELECT mid,IFNULL(pid,0) pid,knt count FROM
(
    SELECT mid,pid,COUNT(id) knt FROM test
    GROUP BY mid,pid WITH ROLLUP
) A WHERE mid IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY mid,IFNULL(pid,0)=0;
```

Here is the output

```
mysql> SELECT mid,IFNULL(pid,0) pid,knt count FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT mid,pid,COUNT(id) knt FROM test
    ->     GROUP BY mid,pid WITH ROLLUP
    -> ) A WHERE mid IS NOT NULL
    -> ORDER BY mid,IFNULL(pid,0)=0;
+------+-----+-------+
| mid  | pid | count |
+------+-----+-------+
|    3 |  15 |     2 |
|    3 |  12 |     2 |
|    3 |  14 |     1 |
|    3 |   0 |     5 |
|    4 |  12 |     1 |
|    4 |  17 |     1 |
|    4 |   0 |     2 |
+------+-----+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is what this means

If you ignore the row result with pid 0, you get

```
+------+----+-------+
| mid  | pd | count |
+------+----+-------+
|    3 | 12 |     2 |
|    3 | 14 |     1 |
|    3 | 15 |     2 |
|    4 | 12 |     1 |
|    4 | 17 |     1 |
+------+----+-------+
```

These counts match your output for the `pid_count`

If you look at the row results with `pid` 0, you get

```
+------+----+-------+
| mid  | pd | count |
+------+----+-------+
|    3 |  0 |     5 |
|    4 |  0 |     2 |
+------+----+-------+
```

These counts match your output for the `mid_count`

Without introducing another subquery, this is my suggested query.

## SUMMARY

The output would have to be used as follows

```
+------+-----+-------+
| mid  | pid | count |
+------+-----+-------+
|    3 |  15 |     2 |
|    3 |  12 |     2 |
|    3 |  14 |     1 |
|    3 |   0 |     5 | <-- Count of mid 3
|    4 |  12 |     1 |
|    4 |  17 |     1 |
|    4 |   0 |     2 | <-- Count of mid 4
+------+-----+-------+
```